# Long to time_format H:i

Tags: php, database, divide

I have the following code im working on an workhours system now my question is

```
$ochtendbreak = "10:00:00";   //begin ochtend pauze
$lunchbreak = "12:00:00";     // begin middag pauze
$middagpauzebreak = "13:30:00";       // begin middag koffie pauze

$ochtendgewerktetijd = "03:00:00";  //minimaal 3 uur gewerkt 
$lunchworkedbreak = "06:00:00";      // minimaal 6 uur gewerkt
$middaggewerktetijd = "03:00:00";       //minimaal 3 uur gewerkt 

$vollewerkdag = "01:00:00";  // alles bij elkaar 1 uur pauze
$lunchpauze = "00:30:00";
$ochtendpauze = "00:15:00";
$middagpauze = "00:15:00";
$nachtdienst = NULL;
while (!$rs->EOF){   
    $workedhours = $rs->fields('workedhours');
    $startworkhours = $lunchbreak - $gewerkteuren;
    $endworkhours = $lunchbreak + $gewerkteuren;
```

as you can see i get workedhours from the database.

now i want to divide it from $lunchbreak ("12:00:00") - $workedhours (that can be anything let's say it's ("06:00:00") it returns (Long = 6) i want to format it to ("06:00:00") how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use date function? Try with something like
date($lunchbreak -$workedhours,('H:i:s');

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$lunchbreak = new DateTime('12:00:00');
$workedhours=new DateTime('6:00:00');

$Time=$lunchbreak->diff($workedhours);
echo $Time->format('"%H:%I:%S" hours');
```

And the output is :

```
"06:00:00" hours
```

Have a look in date-time functions of php:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 1):

it would be great if you use complete date and then you can either fetch the difference from mysql (if you are using)

```
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMEDIFF(endDate, startDate)))
```

OR in PHP

```
$date1 = new DateTime("now");//just for example
$date2 = new DateTime("tomorrow"); //just for example
$dteStart = new DateTime($strStart); 
$dteEnd   = new DateTime($strEnd); 
$dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
$diffStr = $dteDiff->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: this will save the time for extracting only time from date time field.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

```
// here we get DateTime object from time string
$lunchbreak = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '12:00:00');
$workedhours = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '06:00:00');
// get interval
$interval = $lunchbreak->diff($workedhours);
// print need value (hours as int)
echo $interval->h;
```